# AMP разрешить доступ к странице в robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

как разрешить доступ к странице amp в robots.txt?

```
пример сыылки site.ru/amp?page=poslednyaya-novost
```

прописываю так для робота гугла, но не срабатывает

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: */amp
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разрешено всё, что не запрещено. Ничего не прописывайте

Comment: И что значит "не срабатывает"?

Comment: здесь https://search.google.com/test/amp проверяю правильность и наличие

Comment: Это хорошо, но на вопрос не ответили. Что значит «не срабатывает»?

Comment: я так понимаю эта запись не срабатывает, не дает доступ к странице User-agent: Googlebot  Allow: */amp

Comment: Кому не дает доступ? Откуда вы знаете, что не дает доступ?

Comment: добавил скрин в вопросе

Comment: `https://www.enterno.ru` из `robots.txt` сотрите и оставьте только `/amp`

Comment: И вообще зачем вы попытались запретить `/amp` для всех остальных? Какой смысл в этом действии?